# can not save kivy file. How to save kivy file?

Tags: python, kivy

I can not save kivy file to my computer. Do you have any suggestions? On my computer, it saves as `better.kv.py` and when I try to put the file extension on it still doesn't save as `better.kv` instead it looks like this [image]

here is the code that I am working with

main.py

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class MyGrid1(Widget):pass

    

class BetterApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid1()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    BetterApp().run()
```

and better.kv

```
<MyGrid1>:
    Label:
        text: ('[b]Hello[/b] [color = ff0099]World[/color]\n')
```

when I run better.kv here is the error

```
line 1
     <MyGrid1>:
stderr:     <MyGrid1>:
     ^
stderr:     ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
stderr: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thank you

Comment: The screenshot shows it named `better.kv`, as intended. What's wrong with it?

Comment: there is a picture of the file in my question. It doesn't let me open that better kivy file and the better.kv cannot find the main.py

Comment: Sounds like you've saved it, your OS just doesn't know what program should open `.kv` files. Try opening it from within whatever text editor you're using.

Comment: I'm using pyzo since it's easy to load and fast. now it says invalid syntax at <MyGrid1>. I guess because it can't find the main.py

Comment: Please post the full error message (with stack trace) in your question.

Comment: I edited my question with the error. is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't *run* `better.kv`. You run `main.py` and it accesses `better.kv` automatically.

Note that as Nour-Allah Hussein pointed out, you still have the inconsistent name of `MyGrid` / `MyGrid1`. If you run `main.py` as-is, `return MyGrid()` will throw a `NameError` because you haven't defined anything named `MyGrid`.

Comment: it's just a black screen when I run main.py

Comment: Then I don't know what to tell you, since I can't reproduce it. I put those two files in the same directory and run `python main.py` and it displays text for me.

Comment: Thank you for helping me during chritsmas. Merry Christmas and Happy new year

Answer (score 2):

Let us verify some points:

*First Point:*

your application folder name is `better` so your `kv` file should be `better.kv`, as the same folder name but with extension `kv`

*Second Point:*

in `class BetterApp(App):` function `def build(self)` you use `return MyGrid()`, but the intended class in your code is different, it is `MyGrid1` as in your code `class MyGrid1(Widget): pass` so your code does not work, because you initiate `MyGrid` and not `MyGrid1`

Comment: for the first point, I save the name as better.kv and when I run the better.kv it says invalid syntaxin line 1 of better.kv. Thank you for pointing out the second one, I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

If you run into this problem:

save the `.py` file as the same place as the `.kv`

secondly:

you have to run file as scrip or redirect `main.py` to the file